# How to find all AutoMap Profiles in solutions and register them

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, automapper

I am working with net core 3.1 and AutoMapper 10.1.1.

I have on different projects in solution scattered  profiles for auto-mapera.

**How can I get a list of all profiles in solutions and register them and not reference every project?**

```
namespace Boilerplate.WepApp.Automap
{
    public class WebAppAutoMap : Profile
    {
    }
}
```

```
namespace Boilerplate.Blogs.Automap
{
    public class BlogsAutoMap : Profile
    {
    }
}
```

And there is an auto-mapper configuration code

```
namespace Boilerplate.WepApp.Automap
{
    public static class AutoMapperExtensions
    {
        public static void AddAutoMapper(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
            {
                mc.AddProfile(new WebAppAutoMap());
                mc.AddProfile(new BlogsAutoMap());
            }).CreateMapper();

            services.AddSingleton(mapper);
        }
    }
}
```

**How can I get a list of all profiles in solutions and register them?**

This is necessary in order not to violate the architecture of the project as a whole.

Comment: try with reflection

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Comment: @Waqas Raja  I didn’t manage to get them by reflection .. help please the example dropped in the answers

Answer (score 2):

AutoMapper have some extensions to scan for AutoMapper classes and register the configuration, mapping, and extensions with the service collection.

You only need to delivery your layers assembly on one of that extensions:

```cs
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddAutoMapper(this IServiceCollection services, Action<IMapperConfigurationExpression> configAction)
        => AddAutoMapperClasses(services, (sp, cfg) => configAction?.Invoke(cfg), null);

    public static IServiceCollection AddAutoMapper(this IServiceCollection services, params Assembly[] assemblies)
        => AddAutoMapperClasses(services, null, assemblies);

    public static IServiceCollection AddAutoMapper(this IServiceCollection services, Action<IMapperConfigurationExpression> configAction, params Assembly[] assemblies)
        => AddAutoMapperClasses(services, (sp, cfg) => configAction?.Invoke(cfg), assemblies);

    ...

}
```

And then, AutoMapper will resolve this:

```cs
private static IServiceCollection AddAutoMapperClasses(IServiceCollection services, Action<IServiceProvider, IMapperConfigurationExpression> configAction,
    IEnumerable<Assembly> assembliesToScan, ServiceLifetime serviceLifetime = ServiceLifetime.Transient)
{
   ...

    var assembliesToScanArray = assembliesToScan as Assembly[] ?? assembliesToScan?.ToArray();

   ...
}
```

Example of an extension method for DI

```cs
public static class ConfigureServices
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddAutoMapper(this IServiceCollection services)
        => services.AddAutoMapper(
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .Where(x => x.FullName?
                    .Contains("Boilerplate") ?? false));
}
```

Or more dynamic

```cs
public static class ConfigureServices
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddAutoMapper(this IServiceCollection services)
        => services.AddAutoMapper(
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .Where(x => x.FullName?
                    .Contains(GetAssemblySuffix()) ?? false));

    private static string GetAssemblySuffix()
        => Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.FullName?.Substring(0, 11);
}
```

Use at Startup

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddAutoMapper();

    ...
}
```

Comment: Clearly the usage is important here, not the implementation :)

Comment: I cannot implement. I need help with implementations of finding all profiles .....

Comment: @Nikita, I added an example.